# Django, сессии для неавторизованных в приватном окне

Tags: django, сессия

Как в Django получить **ключ сессии** для неавторизованного пользователя в **приватном окне**, если его нет?

```py
def get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    print(request.session.session_key)

# Не авторизованный
>>> None 

# Авторизованный
>>> <строка сессии>
```

Указание `SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'` не помогло.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам `signed_cookies` вообще нужен

Comment: А если ключ сессии ещё не создан, то его следует просто взять и создать через [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#the-sessionstore-object) или [cycle_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.cycle_key)

Answer (score 1):

Мда... Ну действительно, откуда взяться сессии, если в ней ничего не сохраняли. Вопрос решен, спасибо

Достаточно было поместить что либо в нее

```py
request.session['test'] = 'test'
```

Comment: Костыль . . . .